# Use jQuery to create numbered list with styled numbers?

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I need to create what looks like an ordered list with colored numbers in a Wordpress site.

I know how to make this by hand in html. There are several ways, but let's say I create a numbered item via an unordered list such as

`<li><span>1. </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>`

I would simple remove the bullets with CSS list-style:none.

However, I have lots of these lists in this site and don't want to edit the html for every one; I'd rather manage them with Wordpress' standard OL so users who don't know HTML can create them.

I guess I will "hang" the numbers with margin-left and negative text-indent.

What's the most efficient way to handle this in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple OL on one page ( will work as well if only one list). Will also work for nested lists:

```
/* loop over each list so indexing of LI is done on per list basis*/
$("ol").each(function(){    
    $(this).children('li').each(function(index) {   
        $(this).prepend("<span>" + (index+ 1) + " </span>");
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're pretty okay on the CSS front and so you're looking for how to put the `span`s at the beginning of the lists.

If so:

```
$("ol > li").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prepend("<span>" + ($this.index() + 1) + " </span>");
});
```

Perhaps also add a class in there so that if JavaScript isn't running, you get the boring old numbers, but if it is you get the styled ones.

```
$this.addClass('styled');
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ulugak/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ulugak/1/edit)

---

Side note: If you can possibly avoid using the `spans` and use the pseudo-selector `:before` instead or some such, that might be better on the browsers that support it.

Comment: can save multiple calls of `index()` by using first argument of `each`... ahh except just realized why... you are only indexing siblngs

Comment: @charlietfl: No, the `index` passed to `each` will be the index *in the set*. The value returned by `$this.index()` will be the index *relative to siblings*. So it matters if you have more than one `ol`.

Comment: right..that's why I updated my comment